# VB-6 Code being skipped

Tags: database, vb6

I have been tasked with finding an error that has completely broken a legacy vb6 system which is used by a team of about 6.

The error is 'Object variable or With block variable not set'. Having stepped through the code for a while I've found this method which creates workspaces and then opens database connections within them.

```
Public Sub OpenDatabases()
'Used for RFI
Set wj = CreateWorkspace("Archive", UserLogonName, UserPassword, dbUseJet)
Set RFIwj = CreateWorkspace("RFI", UserLogonName, UserPassword, dbUseJet)
Set RRwj = CreateWorkspace("RRI", UserLogonName, UserPassword, dbUseJet)
Set db = wj.OpenDatabase(DriveToUse & "\archive.mdb.mdb", , , "UID=" & UserLogonName & ";PWD=" & UserPassword)
Set RFIdb = RFIwj.OpenDatabase(DriveToUse & "\RMCS\RFI.mdb", , , "UID=" & UserLogonName & ";PWD=" & UserPassword)
Set RRdb = RRwj.OpenDatabase(DriveToUse & "\RMCS\RR.mdb", , , "UID=" & UserLogonName & ";PWD=" & UserPassword)
End Sub
```

When stepping through the code it makes it to the first line where wj is set and then simply exits the method leaving the variables unset.

I have limited experience with any flavour of VB so any suggestions as to why this is happeneing would be great.

Cheers.

Comment: We'd probably need to see the contents of `CreateWorkspace` to be even vaguely hopeful of helping.

Comment: `CreateWorkspace` throws an exception which takes you out of `OpenDatabases` to an external error handler that ignores it?

Comment: Next time do not confuse VB6 with VB.NET. They are two different languages

Comment: What I don't see in you code is an error handler. Add an error handler, then examine the error. MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266173(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: An error / exception is bein raised in Create Workspace. You need to find where it is being raised. Somewhere in the vb6 settings there is something to tell the debugger to break on all errors (I forget exactly where). Set that on, then the debugger will stop on the line causing the error.

Comment: ... Documentation [says the setting is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231225(v=vs.60).aspx) menu option Tools-Options, General tab, check the box "break on all errors"

Comment: @Moo-Juice @MarkJ `CreateWorkspace` is a DAO command, not user-created code.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821374.aspx

Comment: @MarkJ That occurred to me as well, but then it also occurred to me that the only way to get the runtime to ignore an error is to have an `On Error Resume Next` in the code.  The command is only in force for the procedure in which it occurs (proc level scope) and there isn't one here.  So I don't think that's the problem.  Seems more likely that there's some weirdness (obscurely documented somewhere probably) in the DAO `CreateWorkspace` method.

Comment: Nick, I would suggest that you set a breakpoint on the line of code beginning with Set RFIwj... If you get it to break there successfully, then evaluate the Err object.  If you don't, I'd try jac's suggestion of using an error handler.  (As a general rule, error handlers should be used for expected errors rather than unexpected ones, though.)

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. In the end it turned out that the developer of the system who has long since left had hardcoded a username and password into the code.. The username had recently been removed from the access list hence breaking the program..

Answer (score 0):

CreateWorkspace is a command related to preparing a connection via DAO to MS Access. Assuming that no code in the VB app was altered and the system just appeared to 'stop working' one day', it is most likely that something in the Access / MS Office config was altered. Check with your system admins and ask what changes were being made around the time of the occurrence of the failure. Whilst that may give you a cause, it is unlikely to give you an answer. Out of interest, the [Jet DAO Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_Data_Access_Objects) says

> Versions of the DAO library prior to 3.6 are not provided or supported in Microsoft Access 2013.

Maybe that is your answer and your admins updated to Office 2015 whilst the systems are using an old copy of DAO.

The answer will probably lie in updating the MS DAO library to match the version of Access / MS Office that was installed. Try googling for 'MS DAO'

It may turn out that MS retired DAO and you need to switch to another data connection technology. This [page tells](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/821765) you how to connect to Access from VB.Net using ADO.